# What does document.write() do?

Tags: javascript

This is a very basic question.
I have this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function write(){
            document.write('Hello2')
        }
        write();
    </script>
```

It shows my complete page. And at the end of page **Hello2** will be displayed.
But when ever I go to developer tools and call **write()**, it will replace my entire body html. Just curious to know.

```
        window.onload=write;// has the same effect. Clear's my page.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When the document is being read and parsed by the browser, if there's a `script` element that calls `document.write`, the output of `document.write` is inserted into the document at that point. Later, though, once the page is fully loaded, if you use `document.write`, it implicitly performs a `document.open`, which wipes out the page and starts writing a new one from scratch.

More on MDN:

- [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write)
- [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.open)

In general, rather than using `document.write` to add content to a page, use the various [DOM methods](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) (either directly, or via a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries)).

Comment: What do you mean by "once the page is fully loaded"? How is it defined? Is it guaranteed that the "page is fully loaded" before `<body onload` runs?

Comment: @Pacerier: "What do you mean by "once the page is fully loaded"?"* The parser has reached the end of the document. *"Is it guaranteed that the "page is fully loaded" before <body onload runs"* Yes. The `load` event on `body` happens very late in the page load process.

Comment: is this behavior documented or does it merely "seems to be how it works"?

Comment: @Pacerier: Which behavior? `document.write`? The `load` event? I mean, the answer is yes, it's just a matter of what spec to point you at.

Comment: The behavior that `document.write` will surely rewrite the entire page if it's placed in `body onload`.

Comment: @Pacerier: That would be the Web APIs section of [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write()).

Comment: This is an evil feature, very had to debug if `document.write()` is sprinkled somewhere in your event handler

Answer (score 7):

When it is executed *after* the page has completed loading, it overwrites the entire content - one of the points raised in the answer to this question: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document.