# Unexpected output with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is a JavaScript code snippet at  http://jsfiddle.net/QWXf4/1/

```
var x = 5;

function PartyWithoutX(person) {
    // This property will go to window and pollute the global object
    dance = function (person) {
        document.write("Hello " + person.getFullName() + ", Welcome to the Party.");
    };

    this.showX = function () {
        // This will change the global x variable
        x = 25;
        document.write("Value of x is " + x);
    };
}

function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};

var dinesh = new Person("Dinesh", "Singh");

var p1 = new PartyWithoutX(dinesh);

document.write(window.dance(dinesh) + "; Enjoy!!");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(p1.showX());
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(window.x);
document.write("<br/>");
```

The output as you can check is

```
Hello Dinesh Singh, Welcome to the Party.undefined; Enjoy!!
Value of x is 25undefined
undefined
```

I was expecting

```
Hello Dinesh Singh, Welcome to the Party; Enjoy!!
Value of x is 25
undefined
```

Why do I get "Party.undefined" and "25undefined" in the output.

Whats going on here?

Comment: Don't just link to your code, put it here.

Comment: just updated the question with the code. please have a look

Comment: First thing to do: **stop using `document.write()`.**

Comment: `document.write` does not just "call" your own function, it prints the returned result.

Comment: you could replace your document.write with console.log() and view the output in your console window.  then reveal what you really want by appending the values to a variable, which then gets appended to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
document.write(p1.showX());
```

you're doing

```
document.write("Value of x is " + x);
```

and after that doing

```
document.write(undefined);
```

because `p1.showX()` returns `undefined`.

But as Pointy pointed, [you should not use `document.write` at all, especially after the document was loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741584/what-does-document-write-do).

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the results of those function calls to `document.write()`.  They don't return anything, so you get those "undefined" results.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
document.write(p1.showX());
```

with

```
p1.showX();
```

Because the first prints the results of pi1.showX() which is undefined.