# My button keeps disappearing in my 99 bottles of beer on the wall program

Tags: javascript

Hey I really don't under stand why my button keeps disappearing on me, I should also mention that I haven't done any javascript in like 2 months so I may be a little rusty.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script language = "JavaScript">
    function Count(){
        var x = "98";
        x--;
        var y = document.write(x + "<p> Bottles of beer on the wall </p>" + x + "<p> bottles of beer You take one down pass it around</p>" + x-- + "<p> of beer on the wall!</p>");
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = y;
    }
    </script>

    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Count" onClick="Count()">
    </form>
    <p id="text">99 Bottles of beer on the wall 99 Bottles of beer you take one down pass it around 98 bottles of beer on the wall!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, as to why it is overwriting the body: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.write#Notes

Answer (score 2):

Remove **`document.write`** which is override the body

```
var y = x + "<p> Bottles of beer on the wall </p>" + x + 
            "<p> bottles of beer You take one down pass it around</p>" + x-- + 
            "<p> of beer on the wall!</p>";
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = y;
```

Here in this answer you can find [What actually `document.write` does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13741662/1671639)?

Answer (score 0):

It's because document.write() overwrites your body.
use this instead:

```
var y = (x + "<p> Bottles of beer on the wall </p>" + x + "<p> bottles of beer You take one down pass it around</p>" + x-- + "<p> of beer on the wall!</p>");
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thin is to not use `document.write()` in this case. That actually writes to the browser. Try this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script language = "JavaScript">
    var x = "98";
    function Count(){
        next = x - 1;
        var y = x + " bottles of beer on the wall " + x + " bottles of beer You take one down pass it     around " + next + " of beer on the wall!";
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = y;
        x--;
        return false;
    }
    </script>

    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="button" value="Count" onClick="Count()">
    </form>
    <p id="text">99 Bottles of beer on the wall 99 Bottles of beer you take one down pass it around 98     bottles of beer on the wall!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You also had some issues with the way you were decrementing `x`.

Comment: So I copied your code but removed x--; because it would decrease it twice and that would cause problems and now when I click on the button nothing happens ?