# What's wrong with this even/odd Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a very simple JS program. I want it to generate 10 random numbers between 1 and 100 and display how many of them are even and how many are odd. I've been looking all over and I can't find why this isn't working. It's displaying 0 even numbers and 10 odd numbers, no matter the combination. What am I overlooking?

```
function main()
{
    var number = 0;
    var totalNumbers = 0;
    var evenNumbers = 0;
    var oddNumbers = 0;

    document.write("Here are ten random numbers between 1 and 100:<br><br>");

    while(totalNumbers < 10)
    {
        number = document.write((Math.floor((Math.random()* 100)+1)) + "<br>");     

        if(number % 2 == 0)
        {
            evenNumbers++;
        }
        else
        {
            oddNumbers++;   
        }

        totalNumbers++; 
    }

    document.write("<br><br>Even Numbers: " + evenNumbers + "<br>" +
                    "Odd Numbers: " + oddNumbers);
}
```

Comment: Every time I see `document.write` I want to cry on the inside.

Comment: Tip: If you are unfamiliar with a specific method, read its documentation on MDN first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write. Or even search for it on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741584/what-does-document-write-do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`document.write()` does not return a number. Store the number in a variable before calling `document.write()`.

```
while(totalNumbers < 10)
{
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random()* 100)+1;
    document.write(number + "<br>");     

    if(number % 2 == 0)
    {
        evenNumbers++;
    }
    else
    {
        oddNumbers++;   
    }

    totalNumbers++; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Still learning the basics, obviously! Works exactly how I wanted :)