# I need a button NOT to disapear

Tags: javascript, button, random

I am making a javascript code that has a button and when I click on it, it displays one of 5 symbols but when I click the button, it shows the random symbol but the button disapears.  I'm new to javascript so can I please get some help?

```
<script>

function slots()
{
    var slot1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    if (slot1 == 0) {
        document.write("\u2663");
    }
    if (slot1 == 1) {
        document.write("\u2665");
    }
    if (slot1 == 2) {
        document.write("\u2666");
    }
    if (slot1 == 3) {
        document.write("\u2660");
    }
    if (slot1 == 4) {
        document.write("7");
    }
}

</script>
<button type="button" value="Spin" name="SPIN"onClick="slots(); return false;"></button>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741584/what-does-document-write-do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `document.write()` the screen refreshes, so I guess you could do something like this:

```
<script>

function slots()
{
    var slot1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    if (slot1 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2663";
    }
    if (slot1 == 1) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2665";
    }
    if (slot1 == 2) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2666";
    }
    if (slot1 == 3) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2660";
    }
    if (slot1 == 4) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "7";
    }

}
</script>

<button type="button" value="Spin" name="SPIN" onClick="slots();">Click</button>
<span id="value"></span>
```

Comment: Not at all, go on. I just added what was needed.

Comment: That's alright, I actually wrote it in a separate answer - in your case I'd switch `if`s to `else if`s for a tiny performance gain (more because it's a good practice to show to beginners).

Comment: @Tuckertcs Glad to help, could you mark my question as the answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly optimized version of otrebla's code, see it in action:

```js
function slots() {
  var slot1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  var value = document.getElementById('value');
  switch (slot1) {
    case 0:
      value.innerHTML = "\u2663";
      break;
    case 1:
      value.innerHTML = "\u2665";
      break;
    case 2:
      value.innerHTML = "\u2666";
      break;
    case 3:
      value.innerHTML = "\u2660";
      break;
    case 4:
      value.innerHTML = "7";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="Spin" name="SPIN" onClick="slots();">Click</button>
<span id="value"></span>
```