# Posting JavaScript array in html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm used to do this via php but now moving to js (newbie) and I can't see why it doesn't work!
Also please any suggestion other than document.write? Because I don't want to delete the html that I would make later.
All I wanted is to post js array values into html table.
when I write: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<table><tr><td>'+item +'</td></tr></table>';` it works but creates table everytime which is wrong

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<span id="demo"></span>

    
<script>
document.write("<table>");
arrayjs.forEach(myFunction);
document.write("</table>");

function myFunction(item) {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+item +'</td></tr>';
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't putting the table rows inside of the table. You shouldn't use `document.write` for this, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741584/what-does-document-write-do

Comment: @WillTaylor table rows are created depending on foreach loop, I think the table isn't seen outside the loop but I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea that you should avoid `document.write` is correct as it's generally considered bad practice and should be avoided where possible. A better approach is to use native methods to create elements and add them to the DOM, such as `createElement()` and `appendChild()`.

You can use this approach to create a `table` and a `tbody` within it. From there the `tbody` has methods which let you create rows, and from there cells within the rows.

Below is an example of how to do this.

```js
let arrayjs = ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'];
let container = document.querySelector('#demo');
tableFromArray(arrayjs, container);

function tableFromArray(arr, container) {
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  
  container.appendChild(table);
  table.appendChild(tbody)
  
  arr.forEach(item => {
    let tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length); // add a new row
    let td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length); // add a new cell within the row
    td.textContent = item;    
  });
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but I'm trying to avoid using "cells" also because they look ugly with the double borders lines especially that I have images to insert in some td elements :(

Comment: If you're building a table you don't have a choice, you have to use `td` cells. That being said, they can easily be styled, or even removed completely, using CSS

Comment: oh yes that's true! I have posted a new answer with another solution that works but I still your solution is the best way to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Create element using `document.createElement` instead of `document.write`.

```
tab = document.createElement("table")
```

Then, use this same function to create table elements and add content using `textContent`. Finally, add new element as child using `appendChild`

```
arrayjs.forEach(item => {
  row = document.createElement('tr')
  tableItem = document.createElement('td')
  tableItem.textContent = item;
  row.appendChild(tableItem)
  tab.appendChild(row);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I think it's better to create elements (it's just that this didn't work for me but you are in the correct way)

Answer (score 0):

**This also works :)**

AS Rory and wwilkowski said, **creating elements** is the best practise but I tried this and it's working too (so I'm posting **to anyone who wants simpler solution**, eventhough I didn't understand why we should use an empty string):

```html
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
      td, th {
      border: 1px solid #999;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id = "test"> </div>
        
    <script>
    var outputHTML = "";
    var animal =["cat","dog","bird","goat"];
    
    // loop over array and create html string
    outputHTML = "<table>";
    for(var i= 0;i<animal.length;i++){
    outputHTML+= "<tr>";
    outputHTML+= '<td>' + animal[i] + '</td>';
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = outputHTML;
    outputHTML+= "</tr>";
    }
    outputHTML+= "</table>";
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```