# <script src=> vs <script>document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently learning JS and I came across these two different codes.

```
<script src="js/add-content.js"></script>
```

then I was asked to change it to

```
<script>document.write('<h3>Welcome!</h3>');
</script>
```

My question is does the second code remove the link to the js file? or does it remain linked since I already ran the "script src" code?

Comment: Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: *"My question is does the second code remove the link to the js file? or does it remain linked since I already ran the "script src" code?"* Huh? If you changed it, then the previous tag isn't in the file anymore. So what do you mean by "change"?

Comment: *"then I was asked to change it to"* I suggest you ask the person who suggested that why they think that's a good idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does document.write() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741584/what-does-document-write-do)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript programs are run from scratch each time the page is loaded.

If you load a page, change a `<script>` element, then reload the page: The second load of the page will not run the code from the original `<script>` element.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load only your js file:
   `<script src="js/add-content.js"></script>`
2. print welcome in your DOM:
   `<script>document.write('<h3>Welcome!</h3>');</script>`
3. Load Js file and and print welcome in your DOM:

```
<script src="js/add-content.js">
</script>`<script>document.write('<h3>Welcome!</h3>');</script>
```